# Replace Double (") to Single Straight line Quote (') in R

Tags: r, quote

I have the following IDs and want to replace the double quote (") with a single straight line quote (').

```
ID<-c("1WK7X6", "TQM6VY", "ZDNZX0", "J495D8", "RGNSW", 
"9ZD31", "9JS84", "NTHDJ4", "H2UA1", "AV9N7", 
"DC5F2B6", "SLL2C2", "MB2Q0", "9C94LR", "KZNFS0", 
"WHBH47", "BHPW9", "CH2TD5", "TN8F", "XHCQ41"
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: The quotes aren't in the stings themselves, just that's just R knows they are strings. Do you want to edit the source code? Or are you really trying to change the values in your vector? Or are you trying to create some kind of output? I think your question currently is very unclear.

Comment: Note that R stores `ID <- c("A","B")` and `ID2 <- c('A','B')` the same. `all.equal(ID,ID2)` returns `TRUE`

Comment: So I can paste the output into an SQL query

Answer (score 1):

Can you print the result of `class(ID)`? If it is a vector of characters, then the double quotes are irrelevant as it is only used to show that each element is a character.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar issue of converting double-quoted character (or quote-less numeric) vector into single-quoted vector separated by commas and surrounded by parentheses so that this new vector could be passed to a SQL query.

```
ID <- c("1WK7X6", "TQM6VY", "ZDNZX0", "J495D8", "RGNSW", 
      "9ZD31", "9JS84", "NTHDJ4", "H2UA1", "AV9N7", 
      "DC5F2B6", "SLL2C2", "MB2Q0", "9C94LR", "KZNFS0", 
      "WHBH47", "BHPW9", "CH2TD5", "TN8F", "XHCQ41")

new_ID <- paste(sQuote(ID, "'"), collapse = ",")
new_ID <- paste0("(", new_ID, ")")
new_ID
```

This works for numeric vectors as well.

```
num <- c(1:10)

new_num <- paste(sQuote(num, "'"), collapse = ",")
new_num <- paste0("(", new_num, ")")
new_num
```